# Help understanding the derivation of the reciprocity relation in Taylor's Classical Mechanics

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

When Taylor discusses length contraction, he defines two frames, $S$ and $S'$, in which $S'$ moves at speed $V$ relative to $S$. He then claims that the speed of $S$ relative to $S'$ is also $V$, stating that

> The details of the argument require some care, but the gist is this: Consider the transformation from frame S to S'. We'll denote it by S $\rightarrow$ S' temporarily. Suppose that, before making this transformation, we were to rotate our axes through 180° about the y (or z) axis, then make the transformation, and then rotate back again. The effect of the rotations is to reverse the direction of the x axis (and finally rotate it back again). The net effect of all three operations is precisely the transformation (S' $\rightarrow$ S). Since the rotations certainly don't change any speeds, we've proved that the speed of S' relative to S is the same as that of S relative to S'.

I am quite perplexed by what is supposed to be happening here. How does flipping the x-axis (of what I'm assuming is frame S), making the transformation, and then flipping the x-axis again equivalent to S' $\rightarrow$ S, instead of S $\rightarrow$ S'? Am I simply misunderstanding what Taylor is attempting to describe?